# Hololens AND Unity3d, UnityEngine.VR.WSA not found

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

Went to build [Holoworld](https://dev.windows.com/en-US/holographic/holograms_101e).

Unity3D Compiler not finding UnityEngine.VR.**WSA**.Input 
Running Unity 5.2, now upgrading to 5.3.3f1. (Personal edition)

Installed: Windows 10 SDK, Visual Studio 2015 Update 1

Any ideas?

So [this](https://dev.windows.com/en-US/holographic/install_the_tools) is just a tease?

Comment: Yes, it is a tease, see the note on the page you linked to "*The download is coming soon.
The Microsoft tools for HoloLens will be available on March 30th.*"

Answer (score 1):

I think UnityEngine.VR.WSA.Input will be part of the HoloLens SDK, which is not available yet.

Comment: According to [this page](https://dev.windows.com/en-US/holographic/install_the_tools) it will be available March 30th.

Answer (score 0):

You need a special version of Unity for Hololens. It is already public, and it is based on the 5.4.0b10 beta version but it is not the same, so go to the proper page to download it:  http://unity3d.com/es/pages/windows/hololens#download